# how to avoid boiler plate with a simple fixture in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a code as follwos in my test_myfunc.py

```
@pytest.fixture
def dummy_string_EN():
    return 'This is an English string.'

@pytest.fixture
def dummy_string_DE():
    return 'Das hier ist Deutsch.'

@pytest.fixture
def dummy_string_FR():
    return 'la maison blanche est tombée'
```

Then I would like to use some of those texts to check my functions:

```
def test_load_language_models(dummy_string_EN):
    tee = myfunc(dummy_string_EN)
    assert tee.language == 'EN'

def test_load_language_models(dummy_string_DE):
    tee = myfunc(dummy_string_DE)
    assert tee.language == 'DE'

def test_other_method(dummy_string_DE):
    tee = myfunc_2(dummy_string_DE)
    Assert tee.attribute3 == 'whatever
```

I have around 6 string variables in 4 different languages which are quite long.
It looks to me that I am missing something since it can not be that I can only make the fixture in any other way than returning it from a function.

Is there any other solution to avoid all that boiler plate? i.e. writing the decorator and then defining a method to return a variable?

thanks.

Ps: later Edit. To be clear I just look for a way to use variables (strings or lists) in hundreds of tests of different methods. Every method gives a different result with the same string input. So there is no pair-wise approach.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is static, nothing mandates that they are supplied using using the fixtures mechanism: you could just use a module level dictionary, and pick whatever string you need inside your test functions using a key. And if the strings are dynamic, you could have an intermediary fixture to pack all language strings in a dictionary, and pass that dictionary to functions, so they can have the language code parametrized instead of hard-coded as a fixture name:

```py
# [per language fixture definition]

@pytest.fixtue
def all_texts(dummy_string_EN, dummy_string_DE, ...):
    strings = {
       "EN": dummy_string_EN,
       "DE": dummy_string_DE,
        ...
    }


@pytest.mark.parametrize("ln_code", ["EN", "DE", ...])
def test_load_language_models(strings, ln_code):
    tee = myfunc(strings[ln_code])
    assert tee.language == ln_code
```

Comment: I added a comment to.my question because even if this answer is a valid one but does not 100% solves the problem I have.